# Taxonomy and URL aliases

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I am developing a product catalog by means of taxonomy, and want to use URL aliases to better reflect the hierarchy. For example, I have a taxonomy product in the following branch:

```
category/subcategory/product
```

The thing I'm sort of surprised is that I have to paste the complete URL path instead of having it automatically glued up out of the aliases of the parent branches, ie. category + subcategory + product

Is there anything I'm doing/understanding wrong? Is that what you guys been through and accepted "as is"?

Artur

Comment: Related: 
http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/9603/taxonomy-in-contextual-filters-for-views and this one 
http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/6744/setting-up-catalog-taxonomy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will want to use the [pathauto](http://drupal.org/project/pathauto) module. This will also required for you to install the [token](http://drupal.org/project/token) module.

Once you have those two modules install you will want to head over to the pathauto settings path at admin/build/path/pathauto.  You will see there's a field-set for Taxonomy. There is also replacements patterns which contains various different tokens you can use to generate your path.

In your case the pattern you want to use looks like this:

```
category/[catpath-raw]
```

This will automatically generate the path for those taxonomy terms based of these categories.

I assume most of this is for 6.x but the same concept applies for 7.x

Comment: Oh, I see. Something lead me to believe that the pathauto is only for 6.x - that it's about the common URL aliases which is already a built-in functionality of 7.x, and installing pathauto into 7.x does not make any sense. You cleared my mind a bit ;-) Thanks a bunch!

Comment: For D7 you may try `[term:vocabulary]/[term:parents:join-path]/[term:name]`